# Is there a table of the matching types for marshaling in P/Invoke & InterOP?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, pinvoke

I am almost buried by how the different dialects of types are matched between .NET world and native world. Such as MFC CList and other stuffs.

I am desperately hoping for this:

- Some kind of table or cheetsheet that lists all the mappings between types of .NET world and native world.
- A table that lists all the types that can be marshaled.

Great thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For information on default type conversion, try [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120(vs.71).aspx) out.

For information on Marhsaling in general, check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae(v=vs.71).aspx) out.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Your answer is a clean shot.

Comment: @smwikipedia Great, glad to hear you were able to get it all sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

The [`UnmanagedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) enum gives a pretty complete list of the target types you want. It covers all the core types available in C atleast. For user defined types in C, you'll need to check if they are typedefs of a standard type, or in the case of structures, you need to rewrite the structure in C# and marshal each field of it manually.

C++ classes (such as MFC) aren't covered here. P/Invoke does not support the `__thiscall` calling convention (ie, class methods). The common scenarios on importing C++ code to C# are to write a COM wrapper for the class using C++/CLI, or to write a C based wrapper from C++ (mark code extern "C"), and then use P/Invoke on the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I appreciate your answer.